# How do I make Jenkins 2.0 execute a sh command in the same directory as the checkout?

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Here's my Jenkins 2.x pipeline:

```
node ('master'){
    stage 'Checkout'
    checkout scm
    stage "Build Pex"
    sh('build.sh')
}
```

When I run this pipeline the checkout puts the code into to the workspace as expected, however instead of expecting to find the script in workspace/ (it's really there!), it looks in an unrelated directory: workspace@tmp/durable-d812f509.

```
Entering stage Build Pex
Proceeding
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ build.sh
/home/conmonsysdev/deployments/jenkins_ci_2016_interns/jenkins_home/jobs/pex/branches/master/workspace@tmp/durable-d812f509/script.sh: line 2: build.sh: command not found
```

How do I modify this Jenkinsfile so that build.sh is executed in the exact same directory as where I checked out the project source code?

Comment: That's really your complete pipeline? Or do you have multiple `node` blocks?

Comment: For now, that's everything. It's the smallest pipeline that demonstrates the bug.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can enclose your actions in `dir`  block.

```
checkout scm
stage "Build Pex"
dir ('<your new directory>') { 
    sh('./build.sh')
}
... or ..
checkout scm
stage "Build Pex"
sh(""" <path to your new directory>/build.sh""")

...
```

`<your new directory>` is place holder your actual directory. By default it is a relative path to workspace. You can define absolute path, if you are sure this is present on the agent.

Comment: What does 'your new directory' stand for? Is it a placeholder?

Comment: Doen't work for me :-( Where do I have to put the shellscript? Right now it's in the root directory of my git repo. I tried to move it to a subdirectory 'buildscripts' and then use `dir('buildscripts') {}` but no luck

Comment: @  Bastian Voigt  : You may need a new question

Comment: The problem I have is exactly the same as the OP had

Comment: Found that directory doesn't always work, sh "cd path && ${cmd}"  should work.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer to the question, and doesn't work unless you create a new sub-directory. The question was how to run scripts from the workdir of the project (root). For me it works fine when you have a sub directory, but does not work when I'm trying to run the script from the project root.

Answer (score 31):

The reason that your script doesn't work is because `build.sh` is not in your PATH.

The `Jenkinsfile` is running a "sh" script, whose entire contents is the string `build.sh`. The *parent* script is in the "@tmp" directory and will always be there - the "@tmp" directory is where Jenkins keeps the Jenkinsfile, essentially, during a run.

To fix the problem, change your line to `sh "./build.sh"` or `sh "bash build.sh"`, so that the `sh` block in the Jenkinsfile can correctly locate the `build.sh` script that you want to execute.

Answer (score 4):

Jenkins create a folder when it make a clone from your project like this:

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/**job-name**@script

For this to work you must set the file as executable if you are in a linux environment and then call the shell script.

Something like this:

```
// Permission to execute
sh "chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}/../${env.JOB_NAME}@script"

// Call SH
sh "${env.WORKSPACE}/../${env.JOB_NAME}@script/script.sh"
```

Comment: As I am facing the same issues i.e. having a bash script located at the root of the project directory, my question is is the name `script.sh` you are using just for example? or does jenkins somehow? "renames" whatever bash script name you have provides to `script.sh`?

Comment: Not sure what this is supposed to mean, but do not do it. There are simple and straightforward answers.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue and dir is not helping, possibly because I am working inside a subdirectory of the tmp dir itself (for reason not germane here).  My code looks like this

```
dir(srcDir){
  sh 'pwd; la -l; jenkins.sh "build.sh"'
}
```

(the `pwd` and `la -l` statements were added just for debugging.  Issue exists w/o them.) With them I get output like:

```
+ pwd
/jenkins/workspace/aws-perf-test@tmp/repos/2
+ ls -l
total 72
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins   394 May 19 12:20 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  4096 May 19 12:20 api-automation
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins   174 May 19 12:20 build-it.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins   433 May 19 12:20 build-release.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins   322 May 19 12:20 build.sh
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  4096 May 19 12:20 ix-core
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  4096 May 19 12:20 ix-java-client
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins  4096 May 19 12:20 ix-rest-models
drwxr-xr-x 4 jenkins jenkins  4096 May 19 12:20 ix-service
drwxr-xr-x 7 jenkins jenkins  4096 May 19 12:20 ixternal
drwxr-xr-x 5 jenkins jenkins  4096 May 19 12:20 ixtraneous-stuff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins   472 May 19 12:20 jenkins.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 16847 May 19 12:20 pom.xml
+ jenkins.sh build.sh
/home/jenkins/workspace/aws-perf-test@tmp/repos/2@tmp/durable-a3ec0501/script.sh: line 2: jenkins.sh: command not found
```

I ultimately did this:

```
dir(srcDir){
  sh 'cdr=$(pwd); $cdr/jenkins.sh "build.sh"'
}
```

Comment: Double check the command ```sh 'pwd; ls -l; jenkins.sh "build.sh"'```.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled all the answers above and for me it worked like this:

```
stage('Run Script'){
    steps {
        script {
            sh('cd relativePathToFolder && chmod +x superscript.sh && ./superscript.sh parameter1 paraeter2')
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Rafael Manzoni @Keith Mitchell and @Jayan

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my script execution working with a simplified derivative of Rafael Manzoni's response.  I wondered about the whole "JOB_NAME@script" thing and found that unnecessary, at least for declarative using our version of Jenkins.  Simply set the access permissions on the workspace.  No need to go any deeper than that.

```
stage('My Stage') {
    steps {
        sh "chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}"
        sh "./my-script.sh"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the executable bit on `build.sh` in your SCM repository, along with an [executable header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) such as

```bash
#!/bin/bash
```

then it should also be executable in the checkout, and so simply

```
sh './build.sh'
```

will work. If you prefer not to have mode bits set on files in your SCM repository (for example because it causes problems for Windows users), simple alternatives include

```
sh 'sh build.sh'
```

or

```
sh 'bash build.sh'
```

(depending on whether it is in fact a pure Bourne shell script, or really Bash), or

```
sh '. build.sh'
```

(This last idiom is potentially error-prone since it will run the script inside the default shell on the agent, which on many Linux distributions will be Bash, but on Debian/Ubuntu will be “Dash” which deliberately blocks Bash-specific features.)

If you do not wish to make the Pipeline script hard-code a particular shell (or other interpreter, such as Python) then include the `#!` header as above but run

```
sh 'chmod a+x build.xml && ./build.xml'
```

Answer (score -1):

## Use the `GIT_CHECKOUT_DIR` environment variable

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Install dependencies') {
      steps {
        dir(GIT_CHECKOUT_DIR) {
          // now everything is executed in your checkout directory
          sh 'yarn'
        }
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Set your `GIT_CHECKOUT_DIR` while setting up your pipeline. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767919/in-jenkins-how-to-checkout-a-project-into-a-specific-directory-using-git):
[image: pipeline-checkout-dir]

List of more environment variables:

- `${YOUR_JENKINS_HOST}/env-vars.html`
- example: `http://localhost:8000/env-vars.html`

The most upvoted answer is dangerous and brittle. No need to use static operating system dependant ABSOLUTE PATHs in multiple places that break your builds once you change the machine.