# Set working directory within codebase at Jenkinsfile/Jenkins config level

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to run your entire Jenkinsfile in the context of a subdirectory of your project?

I have seen countless [Stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143485/how-do-i-make-jenkins-2-0-execute-a-sh-command-in-the-same-directory-as-the-chec) suggesting that I run each `sh` within a `dir` block

```
dir ('sub/project/dir/') { 
  sh('build.sh')
}
```

If you have 7 different Jenkins pipelines with multiple `stage`'s, this is a lot of copy/paste and not ideal. Is there a way to run the entire pipeline in the `sub/project/dir/` directory?

I'm looking for an answer that I could maybe put in the Jenkins configuration when setting up the pipeline through the Jenkins UI

I also tried `Check out to a sub-directory` in `Additional Behaviors`, however, this will throw an error anytime you try to do anything `git` related saying there is no `.git` file. If this is the only way to achieve this, am I missing something on how to preserve the root directory's .git file?

Answer (score -2):

Hi Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53664214/10727144) answer .If you use this option then you dont need to use Check out to a sub-directory.