# checkoutToSubdirectory not affecting downstream stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I found checkoutToSubdirectory in the [Jenkins pipeline docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) and in the build console I am seeing output saying `Running in /home/ec2-user/workspace/projectDir/subDir` but then when the first

```
stage('install/fetch dependencies') {
  steps {
```

block it gets run in the normal workspace `projectDir`, not `subDir`. What else do I need to add to ensure my `stages` are run in the `subDir`?

Answer (score -2):

The checkoutToSubdirectory don't change the workspace for the build. You can change your workspace by setting WORKSPACE environment at the starting of stages. Use below lines to change workspace

```
pipeline{
    agent { label 'master' }
    environment { 
    WORKSPACE="${WORKSPACE}/subdir" 
    }
    stages{}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Amit , however, this does not work as intended. If I run `sh "pwd"` in a stage then it will show the script is running in `WORKSPACE` not `WORKSPACE/subdir`