# how to configure Jenkins job for copying files from git to a server

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

i want to configure a Jenkins job for pushing the files from gitlab to a remote server when a user made any changes or commit to a particular project. Previously i am manually copying the files from local machine  to a  remote server via winscp. So guys can someone help me to set the settings accordingly to my requirement.

I have 
1) Remote server
2)gitlab( a repository is created in the gitlab)
3) i have files to be copied to a remote server in my local machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Jenkins, how to checkout a project into a specific directory (using GIT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767919/in-jenkins-how-to-checkout-a-project-into-a-specific-directory-using-git)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understood your need...

Checkout and Pull the GIT repository, it will trigger the job once a commit is made, then use something like the plugin below

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin

or an ANT task or a Bash script or any other routine, to copy the file from the Jenkins workspace to the server, hope it helps...