# Checkout Code to remote directory using GIT Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

Is it possible to checkout code to a remote directory using GIT Plugin in Jenkins.

Thanks and regards
Prashanth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Jenkins, how to checkout a project into a specific directory (using GIT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767919/in-jenkins-how-to-checkout-a-project-into-a-specific-directory-using-git)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to feed your jenkins build with your git commands

[image: shell in Jenkins]

And this is also done through the git jenkins plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

as shown in their example:

```
Started by user anonymous
Checkout:workspace / C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\.hudson\jobs\watir\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1a1f370
Last Build : #4
Checkout:workspace / C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\.hudson\jobs\watir\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1a1f370
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
$ git clone -o origin git://github.com/bret/watir.git "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\.hudson\jobs\watir\workspace"
```

Comment: How do I add a path to my remote directory (i.e my share folder path)

Comment: You can feed it into your git command. Basically Jenkins let you replicate any shell workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a big problem. I'm sending you to an earlier article.

[In Jenkins, how to checkout a project into a specific directory (using GIT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767919/in-jenkins-how-to-checkout-a-project-into-a-specific-directory-using-git)

Hope it will help a lot.